# How to use map() on lists with different length, fill shortest lists with custom value

Tags: python

I want to apply a function on multiple lists using map, and fill the shortest list(s) with a custom value. I have created a solution using a for loop and zip_longest but I think it could be improved using `map()`. I'm unaware which of the list(s) is the longest, they could have equal lengths. Here's my implementation:

```
import itertools

items1 = [1, 2, 3, 4]
items2 = [1, 2]
items3 = [1, 1, 1]

def multiply(a, b, c):
    if a is None:
        a = 0.5  # custom value, could also be set elsewhere
    if b is None:
        b = 0.4
    if c is None:
        c = 0.3
    return a * b * c

squared_numbers = []
for numbers in itertools.zip_longest(items1, items2, items3):
    squared_numbers.append(multiply(*numbers))
```

Value of `squared_numbers`:

```
[1, 4, 1.2000000000000002, 0.48]
```

Bonus: I prefer to set the custom values via `def multiply(a=5, b=0.4, c=0.3)`, but I'm not sure if this is possible.

**EDIT:** The code works fine, I'm just curious if it can be optimized further.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what is the question. Is something wrong with the code? Is it not your expected output?

Comment: @Tomerikoo the code works fine, I'm curious if the code can be optimized further

Comment: Then you might want to ask on [codereview.se]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you meant `itertools.starmap` instead of `map`? Here's something I came up with but I wouldn't really say it's better than what you've already written:

```
from itertools import zip_longest, starmap

lists = [
    [1, 2, 3, 4],
    [1, 2],
    [1, 1, 1]
]

def multiply(*args):
    from functools import reduce
    from operator import mul

    defaults = [0.5, 0.4, 0.3]

    return reduce(mul, (arg or default for arg, default in zip(args, defaults)))


squared_numbers = list(starmap(multiply, zip_longest(*lists)))

print(squared_numbers)
```

Output:

```
[1, 4, 1.2000000000000002, 0.48]
>>>
```

If you're using `itertools.zip_longest`, you can't really get around using a `fillvalue` - in our case that means we will always pass three arguments to `multiply`, even if all- or some of them are `None` (`itertools.zip_longest`'s default `fillvalue`). This means you can't use default positional-arguments, because they only take effect when not enough positional-arguments are passed in, which will never be the case.

The generator expression in `functools.reduce` works through short-circuit evaluation. The expression `arg or default` will evaluate to `arg` if `arg` is truthy, and `default` otherwise. `None` is considered falsey, so if `arg` is `None`, the expression evaluates to `default`.